# htaccess domain.com/sub to sub.domain.com

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

What I want: example.com/sub to be sub.example.com/
I created a subdomain and the host doesnt provide other help than an url to generate a htaccess file. It has 2 values "subdomain" and "folder".

In subdomain I wrote "https://example.com/sub" and in folder i wrote the foldername: "sub".

It gave me this that is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://example\.com/sub
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Would you change folder location? I think your subdomain folder effects from .htaccess to your root folder. Btw do you use CPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the url scheme from your `%{HTTP_HOST}` condition . and your `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://example\.com/sub` condition should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$` .

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: As intended. Thank you